# Sync a video stream at two separate receivers

Tags: video, ffmpeg, stream, synchronization, vlc

I want to use two separate receivers which both are receiving the same video stream. One of the receivers does some processing tasks and pass the results to the other receiver (using web-socket or a RESTFUL API) so that the second receiver displays the results and play the video(the frames and result values should be synchronized in the second receiver). The actual issue is how to synchronize these receivers over the IP network. 
Note that it is highly preferred that each one can read the stream by its own and I want to prevent resending the stream to the other receiver. A possible solution can be extracting timestamp in both receivers but I am not sure if it is possible. Can anyone help me how I can find a good solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Synching video playback on separate devices is a tricky problem - most solutions use some sort of feedback from the devices to a central synching server which then instructs the individual players to speed up or slow down as appropriate.

Some examples do exist, although you will have to experiment to see if they meet your needs:

An open source client based solution:

- https://github.com/Syncplay/syncplay

A couple of browser based solutions:

https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c0bc/b42b63b6d88ebbb5fb4c6686662300d3611b.pdf
https://github.com/povdocs/sync-player